# Mac stuck at the loading bar, when trying to boot from macOS Catalina Patcher

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, startup

I want to install Catalina on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) with 10.13.6 (High Sierra) installed. Therefore I made a bootable USB drive with the [macOS Catalina Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/). First, I had the problem that the USB drive wasn't recognized. Now I used another USB drive and now it will let me boot from. But it always is stuck at the loading screen (nearly 100%). What I'm doing wrong?

I tried safe mode (with <kbd>shift</kbd>), reset the NVRAM/PRAM (with <kbd>opt+cmd+P+R</kbd>) and I don't see a value in reinstalling MacOs in my case.

What can I do to successfully boot from the USB drive?

Comment: I would want to verify that the patcher has not modified the install in a way that makes it non-bootable on your Mac. Make a bootable installer of your current OS and verify you can fully boot to the "ready to install" screen. If not there may be another issue with your Mac. If it does then the patched version of Catalina may be a non-starter (literally) for your Mac.

Comment: I tried that and I can boot from it and the `mac OS utilites` dialog appears, where i can install macOS.

Comment: Then I would venture that the issue is with the modified Catalina installer. Process of elimination, you see...

Comment: Yeah, but what can I do? I did the creation of the USB installer multiple times. I could give it another try, but there are not much things I could do ...

Comment: That patcher (or possibly *any* that patch Catalina) **doesn't work** for you. So find a working method for your system or give up the quest for running unsupported macOS on your Mac. Sorry but seems like all that is left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I deleted the patcher and everything related to it from the machine. Then re-download the tool and also created the bootable USB drive again. I was able to boot from the drive and also install `Catalina`. But the MacBook again hang at nearly 100%. Then I restarted the machine and the setup dialog appeared! **Yes, my MacBookPro8,1 is supported!**

As an alternative I'd have tried [another patcher](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-15-catalina-on-unsupported-macs.2183772/).

Comment: The alternative that you tried... is it the unsupported/discontinued [macOS Patcher](https://gitlab.com/0403979/macos-patcher)?

Comment: I‘ve not tried it, but I’d try one of two other listed on the link in my answer (one is the discontinued one yes)